# Can warrants to buy stock contain conditions or stipulations other than price?

Tags: investing, stocks, warrants

Can warrants to buy stock contain conditions or stipulations other than price?

Comment: They might expire, eventually.

Comment: See this answer http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/647/what-is-a-stock-warrant-how-do-warrants-work/662#662

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of conditions, yes.

Most commonly is a limitation on the exercise date.  The two more common would be *American* which is exercisable any time, and *European* which are only exercisable on their expiry date.

Sometimes they may be linked to the original asset, and might only be convertible to stock if that original asset is given/sold back to the company.  (Effectively perhaps making the bond convertible to stock).

Lots more details on the [Pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_%28finance%29), but in short, basically you need to read the warrant *contract* individually, as each will differ.